# How to present Popover from XLForm Button?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, xlform

I'm trying to present a popover when someone touches an XLForm button on iPad.

The selector passes me an XLFormDescriptor object, but I can't figure out how to get the frame of the button so I can show the popover from it.

A nudge in the right direction would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [sender cellForFormController:self];
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = cell.frame;
```